# CSS - анимация (не срабатывает стиль анимации)

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

Почему в данном примере анимация действует одинаково?
Почему не срабатывают её опции такие как:
[linear, ease, ease-in, ease-out, ease-in-out]?
*(Делаю первые шаги в анимации - строго не судите)*

```css
    .anim{
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#800053;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:4px;
    animation:animate 4s infinite;
    -moz-animation:animate 4s infinite;
    -webkit-animation:animate 4s infinite;
     display:inline-block;
    }
    #element_1 {
    animation-timing-function:linear;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    }
    #element_2 {
    animation-timing-function:ease;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:ease;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease;
    }
    /* остальные для проверки эффекта*/
    #element_3 {
    animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    }
    #element_4 {
    animation-timing-function:ease-out;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-out;
    }
    #element_5 {
    animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    }
    @keyframes animate {
    50%{
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-top:50px;
      }
    }
    
    
    @-moz-keyframes animate {
    50%{
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-top:50px;
      }    
    }
    /*from {margin-left:0px;} - это когда в одну лишь сторону
    to {margin-left:50px;}*/
    
    @-webkit-keyframes animate {
    50%{
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-top:50px;
      }    
    }
    /*from {margin-left:0px;} - это когда в одну лишь сторону
    to {margin-left:50px;}*/
```

```html
    <div id="element_1" class="anim">up-down-1</div>
    <div id="element_5" class="anim">up-down-2</div>
```

пример:
http://jsfiddle.net/tw9w3eoh/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо было разделить блоки между собой. так как вы прописали ***display: inline-blok*** в классе ***anim***, поэтому были видны залипания одного из блоков когда указывали им разные свойства анимации.

```css
.anim {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #800053;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  animation: animate 4s infinite;
  -moz-animation: animate 4s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: animate 4s infinite;
}
#element_1 {
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
#element_2 {
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}
/* остальные для проверки эффекта*/

#element_3 {
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
#element_4 {
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
#element_5 {
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  margin-left: 0.10in;
}
@keyframes animate {
  50% {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes animate {
  50% {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
}
/*from {margin-left:0px;} - это когда в одну лишь сторону
to {margin-left:50px;}*/

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  50% {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
}
/*from {margin-left:0px;} - это когда в одну лишь сторону
to {margin-left:50px;}*/
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <div id="element_1" class="anim">up-down-1</div>
    <div id="element_5" class="anim">up-down-2</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ.